# Вставка значения в колонку большего, чем максимальный размер колонки varying(20)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.6

Происходит следующая проблема:

В колонку типа `varying(20)` вставляется строка с количеством символов больше 20-и. Postgres выбрасывает ошибку о том, что строка не может влезть.

Есть ли какой-то способ обрезать слишком длинные значения при вставке автоматически, параметр какой-нибудь указать?

Comment: Гораздо разумнее изменить тип данных... до размера в 126 это не потребует дополнительного пространства.

Comment: В добавление к того, что сказал @Akina - Или изменить тип данных на `text`, без ограничения. Тогда все дороги открыти для Вас. Если хотите ограничить размер строки - используйте `check constraint`. Если хотите обрезать - используйте trigger `on before insert or update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невозможно.

В том числе триггерами: триггеры вызываются только после проверки типов данных, и, соответственно, только после проверки длины текста в `varchar(20)`

Comment: а если использовать rule?

Comment: @nörbörnën, попробуйте. Лучшая моя попытка закончилась на `infinite recursion detected in rules`